# Is there a way to elevate certain installers from non-admin users without entering password?

Tags: deployment, installation, windows-10, elevated-privileges

We have Windows 10 tablets being used in the field by our reps and some customers. They log in with an account that doesn't have administrative privileges. From time to time  we have to send them new software updates. These installers need to run elevated to work properly. We don't want to give the reps admin passwords so ideally we want to white list certain installers that they can elevate themselves when run from a standard account without the user entering a password.

I hope this makes sense. The best we have come up with is to write and install a Windows service that runs elevated and would run our installers.

But I wonder if there is a better solution. Ideally I would like to tell Windows that it should auto-elevate installers from a certain publisher or something similar.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no way to *auto-elevate* anything. If you could do so, it would pretty much defeat the entire purpose of UAC. Even your service solution would require an elevated user to install it.

Comment: Yes, the service would be installed by an admin before sending the device to the reps.

It seems it would be a pretty useful feature to be able  to set a policy to allow certain whitelisted apps to run elevated from a standard account. I am sure we are not the only ones that have this problem.

Comment: So you have your solution, right? An elevated service, installed by an administrative user, that will run your installers?

Comment: The problem is that the service can't bring up a UI which requires silent installers.